# Is the volume equivalent of every odd dimension conserved after deformations?

Tags: calculus, geometry, volume, transformation

I don't know the best way to phrase this (english isn't my main language), so I'll do my best.

First we have the perimeter (one dimension, a line), which is conserved after a deformation. for example if you have a square and deform it (by this I mean you alter its shape but essentially the line which conforms it, is the same, just in a different shape, you can maybe build a triangle using that same line or something) then the perimeter is the same.

In R^3 the volume of an object is also conserved after deformation.
But in R^2 this doesn´t happen with the area. In the previous example of altering a square, it will keep its perimeter but not necessarily its area.

Because of this I had this question. Does this happen for all odd dimensions (R^(2n+1)), if so why?

I'll be happy to clarify anything.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define the deformations that have these properties? There are linear transformations in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which do preserve area, and linear transformations in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which do not preserve volume.

Comment: I'm not sure, I was thinking it in real world terms. In the real world deforming an object keeps its volume, the same with perimeter. The volume in particular is related to density. mass/volume=density, and mass and density should stay the same. Tbh I don't really know the math equivalent of the deformations I'm talking about, maybe you could help me there.

Comment: You have a specific image in mind for a deformation, but mathematically that isn't what all deformations are. For example you believe that if we move a piece of string in the shape of a square (or "deform" it as you are imprecisely saying) the string does not change length but the area it encloses will because that is your experience with strings in real life. However, you could also imagine the "deformation" of a thin droplet of water or an amoeba: the area of the droplet or amoeba never changes, yet its perimeter changes constantly as it moves.

Comment: Therein lies the problem with ascribing real world limitations and physical intuition to mathematics - you can define all the "deformations" you want which preserve perimeter, surface area, etc. But that is because *you* defined it that way and *you* created the rules of the game, so of course those properties were preserved. Claiming that there was some mathematically intrinsic property to the dimensionality of the objects would be circular logic.

Comment: Density changes.

Comment: @Aruralreader wdym, it shouldn't

Comment: @NinadMunshi I understand, I thought it was general knowledge that perimeter and volume are preserved after deformations. At least that's what I was taught, so I assumed people knew what I meant. Now I see that I was wrong, I was hoping there was a mathematical definition for these "intuitive deformations" I was talking about, but It seems that is not the case. Thanks for taking the time to answer me.

Comment: @Aruralreader What I mean is like if you have a ball of clay and you punch it, It changes its shape, but its mass and its density remain the same. This would be a "deformation".

Comment: There is a such thing called measure preserving maps, have a look at the most famous result of these mappings called the Poincare Recurrence Theorem.